# Redo an action & stop it with a condition

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an android app & i need to know how to redo an action till some condition happens.
I tried to do this:

```
while (!b.ButtonClicked()) {

    doThisAction();

     }
```

This will never stop (infinity) because the action listener is outside the loop (while) so the condition isn't going to be satisfied.
I hope you understand me ...

Comment: Use a listener instead of a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a flag for the purpose.

```
//YourActivity
public static Boolean BUTTON_CLICKED_FLAG=false;
```

now you can use a function like

```
public initInfiniteLoop(){

    //starts the loop 
    while(BUTTON_CLICKED_FLAG){
    //your code here 

    }
}
```

Within your onClick() method for the button just toggle the flag BUTTON_CLICKED_FLAG and start the loop if it's not started yet.

```
onClick(){
//first toggle the status
YourActivity.BUTTON_CLICKED_FLAG=!YourActivity.BUTTON_CLICKED_FLAG;

//then initiate loop if it is not already started
if(YourActivity.BUTTON_CLICKED_FLAG=true){
initInfiniteLoop();
//you can replace the if condition and function with the loop if you want. 
}
}
```

If the loop is already running , it will stop when we change the static value BUTTON_CLICKED_FLAG to false.

Even though it will work, I would prefer a thread for the purpose.

Comment: it's an infinite loop, the problem is that the loop starts from a button & stops from the same button.

Answer (score 0):

Set a counter variable to 0 and inside the onCLick of the method of the button  set its value to 1.

```
  while(c==0)
```

run while till c==0 check and tell me if it works

Comment: i tried this, i doesn't work .... The problem is that the clickListner waits till the loop finishes... 
So in your solution, the var "c" would never get the value 1

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check condition: if true then do something

        }
    });
```